# how to group a data frame based on more than one column and split one column?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a data set with four columns, whose data I want to classify based on its first three columns and count how many times the first columns contains a positive, zero, or negative value. I also want to sum up the values of column 4 in each state (positive/zero/negative) for each classification.
Here is an example:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
----------------------------
1       a       Jack    2
1       a       Jack    3
2       c       Joe     0
3       c       Joe     -1
3       a       Joe     1
1       a       Jack    -2
```

The results should look like this:

```
col1    col2    col3    PCount  PSum   ZCount  ZSum   NCount  NSum
------------------------------------------------------------------
1       a       Jack    2       5      0       0      1       -2
2       c       Joe     0       0      1       0      0       0
3       c       Joe     0       0      0       0      1       -1
3       a       Joe     1       1      0       0      0       0
```

`PCount and PSum` are the number of times (1 , a , Jack) has a positive value in `col4` and its summation, respectively. `ZCount and ZSum` contain the number of times (1 , a , Jack) has a zero value in `col4` and its summation, respectively. `NCount and NSum` show the number of times (1 , a , Jack) has a positive value in `col4` and its summation, respectively. the same is true for the rest of the rows.

Any suggestions for how to code this in python (or probably sqlite)? my data set is rather large (+12M rows).

(I have asked a similar version of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761634/how-to-accumulate-and-operate-on-a-data-set-based-on-the-values-of-more-than-one) and also provided my code, which does not work correctly!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With conditional aggregation after grouping by col1, col2, col3:

```
select col1, col2, col3,
  sum(col4 > 0) PCount,
  sum(case when col4 > 0 then col4 else 0 end) PSum,
  sum(col4 = 0) ZCount,
  0 ZSum,
  sum(col4 < 0) NCount,
  sum(case when col4 < 0 then col4 else 0 end) NSum
from tablename
group by col1, col2, col3
```

There is no need for calculation of `ZSum`, right?
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kCJJV6BiLTQDUBgTeQvsKh/1).
Results:

```
| col1 | col2 | col3 | PCount | PSum | ZCount | ZSum | NCount | NSum |
| ---- | ---- | ---- | ------ | ---- | ------ | ---- | ------ | ---- |
| 1    | a    | Jack | 2      | 5    | 0      | 0    | 1      | -2   |
| 2    | c    | Joe  | 0      | 0    | 1      | 0    | 0      | 0    |
| 3    | a    | Joe  | 1      | 1    | 0      | 0    | 0      | 0    |
| 3    | c    | Joe  | 0      | 0    | 0      | 0    | 1      | -1   |
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really useful at the time of writing, but the upcoming sqlite 3.30 (Currently in beta) supports `FILTER` clauses for aggregate functions, allowing for something like

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, col3
     , count(col4) FILTER (WHERE col4 > 0) PCount
     , total(col4) FILTER (WHERE col4 > 0) PSum
     , count(col4) FILTER (WHERE col4 = 0) ZCount
     , 0 ZSum
     , count(col4) FILTER (WHERE col4 < 0) NCount
     , total(col4) FILTER (WHERE col4 < 0) NSum
FROM tablename
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3;
```

which is cleaner than scattering a bunch of `CASE`'s around like you have to now. (`total()` is a sqlite specific function that's like `sum()` but returns 0 instead of `null` on an empty set of rows).